# Eliminate duplicated rows based on another column in R

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I really need your help!

I did this dataframe to help you understand my problem:

`df <- data.frame(code = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E'), Value = c('high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'low', 'medium'))`

What I need to do is:

- eliminate duplicates from the first column based on the second column, so if we have a duplicate and between those rows is present the value 'high' pick that one, otherwise look for 'medium' and in the end 'low'.

In the end I would like to obtain the following dataframe:

```
final_df <- data.frame(code = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
                      Value = c('high', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'medium))
```

I don't know how to do it, I tried with nested for loops plus several if's but it does not work properly..
Thanks in advance to who is going to help.

Answer (score 2):

We can `arrange` the columns and then do `distinct` on the 'code' column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 arrange(code, match(Value, c("high", "medium", "low"))) %>% 
 distinct(code, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
  code  Value
1    A   high
2    B   high
3    C    low
4    D medium
5    E medium
```

---

If we want a `base R` solution

```
df1 <- df[with(df, order(code, match(Value, c("high", "medium", "low")))),]
df1[!duplicated(df1$code),]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun , there would be a way without creating a tibble? Or maybe is it possible to convert the tibble in a dataframe? Since I don't know how to work with tibbles..

Comment: sorry if I'm bothering you, but even the last code produces a tibble ... After eliminating duplicates I need to reshape my dataframe.. but R does not let me to do it because the dataframe is now a tibble... can you help me?

Comment: @MartinaNoliMaio your original data is `data.frame` and in the `base R`, i used only base R functions.  If it is returning tibble, your input must be tibble.  Yoou can convert to data.frame with `df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)`

Comment: thanks again... I really don't know what happened.. but know it works! Thanks

Comment: @MartinaNoliMaio I am not getting what you are getting  `is_tibble(df1)#
[1] FALSE`

Comment: This is a better solution if the code column is type Date.

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
   group_by(code) %>%
   slice_max(factor(Value, c('low', 'medium', 'high')))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   code [5]
  code  Value 
  <chr> <chr> 
1 A     high  
2 B     high  
3 C     low   
4 D     medium
5 E     medium
```